# android-studio software setup in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: android-studio

I haven't downloaded Java. I installed android-studio with ./studio.sh. during this jdk and sdk were downloaded I previously downloaded android-studio  and unconpressed using tar -xf command.
Bala, india